# python: class name is not defined

Tags: python, module, importerror

I am getting the error "name is not defined "  when instantiating a class object in another file. what is causing this and how do I fix it?
I know there are other posts with the same questions, but the fixes for those  didn't work for me.

in classFile.py

```
class P:
    def __init__(self):
        pass
class C(P):
    def __init__(self):
        pass
if __name__ == "__main__":
    c1 = C() #no error
```

in main.py

```
import classFile
if __name__ == "__main__":
    foo = C() #errors
```

gives the error "C isn't defined".

when I instantiate foo as below, I get the error I get the error "classFile 'shelf' has no attribute 'C'

```
foo = classFile.C()
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to explicitly mention you are using a class from `classFile`:

```
foo = classFile.C()
```

Alternatively, you could replace your `import` with:

```
from classFile import C
```

and keep your current usage.